# Flask error when using template

Tags: python, flask

trying to start a server using flask and get this error. My template file is in the template folder (flaskr/templates)

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
     abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/templates/')
@app.route('/templates/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

I get the error:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

Comment: It says the URL is wrong... So did you go to `/hello/`? Or to `/`? Or something else? You should always describe what you did to get the error.

Comment: sorry updated code.  I just ran the code and get an error when i go to the server url

Comment: What do you mean with "server url"? Which URL *exactly* are you typing in the browser's address bar?

Comment: local host (http://127.0.0.1:5000/ )

Comment: Right, but you *only* defined routes for `/templates/`, so I would expect `http://localhost:5000/templates/` and `http://localhost:5000/templates/hello` to work. I'm not sure what behaviour you were expecting?

Comment: Sorry umm i described the error more accurately in the below sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be something wrong with your application structure

it should be like this (Directory structure)

Test/

----hello.py

----templates/

--------index.html

--------hello.html

## hello.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/templates/')
@app.route('/templates/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('home.html', name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

## index.html

```
<h1> Index page</h1>
```

## hello.html

```
<h1> Home </h1>
<h1> Hello {{name}}</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to provide a route for templates, flask handles that for you automatically.

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, session, g, redirect, url_for, \
     abort, render_template, flash

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/<name>')
def hello(name=None):
    return render_template('index.html', name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: Hi,
I still get the error. I checked my html file and it has no errors (only has <title>"HI"</title>)

Comment: You need to save the file and then run the server again; then go to `http://localhost:5000/` or `http://localhost:5000/hello` - in your template, you need to have `<html><head><title>Hi</title></head><body>Welcome {{ name }}</body></html>`

Comment: still get Internal Server Error

Comment: Tried app = Flask(__name__,template_folder= "/Users/TDE/Desktop") still doesnt work